# Get data from express to form in html

Tags: html, angular, express

there is a small and simple example.
I want to check if the data is in the server (for instance if the person is signed). If it is in the server, I know I can res.redirect in express to move on, but if it doesn't, how do I get the response from the server in the html, and not with angular or so, for example pop up a message if he isn't recognized in the db.

```
<form action="/IsSIgn" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name">
<button type="submit">sign in</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

```
res.send("<script>window.alert('unauthorized');</script>")

  
res.send("<script>window.alert('unauthorized');window.location.href='/example-page-route'</script>")
```

Solution 2:

Make another html page for invalid name
and redirect to, that page

Comment: Where do I receive this data in the html?

Comment: And after it pops up the page is blank

Comment: for the data you have to implement fetch method or ajax request. after pops you can reload window or redirect again to the sign in page. for that you have to use window.location.href and for reload window.location.reload() as i mentioned in solution